# Объединенные данные из входящих пакетов по websocket

Tags: websocket

Обмен идет бинарными данными по протоколу websocket между сервером (c++) и клиентом (jscript). Сервер, время от времени, отсылает сразу несколько "пакетов". В итоге, на клиенте приходит только одно событие onmessage. Но в ArrayBuffer содержатся данные более чем одного "пакета" websocket. Можно ли как-то узнать сколько все-таки "пакетов" пришло?
P.S.: Изобретать еще один протокол поверх websocket (с длиной, id и т.п.) это как-то криво.

Comment: я б посмотрел в сторону смены библиотеки на сервере, это скорее всего её ошибка.